# limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}$ without Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to find $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}$$ without l'Hospital's rule?

I have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$ proved without H. but it doesn't help me with this complicated limit (however I'm sure I have to use it somehow).

I know the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$, so I tried to estimate: $0<\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}\le\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{\tan x}{x}+g(x)$ with various $g$ and prove that $g(x)\to 0$, but with no result.

Comment: Also without power series?

Comment: yes, I'm interested in solution without power series also, but estimations taken from power series, which can be proven without the whole theory of power series (like $\sin x\ge x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ for $x\ge 0$) are ok.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and the sine/cosine duplication formulas are enough, but it is quite a tour-de-force.

Comment: tanx/(x^2 *tanx)  -x/(x^2tanx)     =1/x^2  -1/(xtanx)  . thus we

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\tan x}{x^2 \tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-\frac{\sin x}{x}}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{(x/2)}}{x^2} $$
gives $L=A+B$ where:
$$ A = -\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos\frac{x}{2}}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{4}}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}=-\frac{3}{8}$$
and
$$ B = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$$
(assuming such a limit exists) fulfills:
$$ 3B = 4B-B = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{2\sin(x/2)}{\sin (x)}-1\right)$$
so that:
$$ B = \frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{\cos\frac{x}{2}}-1\right)=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{4}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{24}$$
and $L=A+B=-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{24}=\color{red}{\large-\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Nice +1. In the step where you write $3B = 4B - B$ you assume that $B$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you get to assume that the limit exists, you can show that
$$\begin{align}L&=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-\tan x}{x^2\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{-\cos x}{\frac{\sin x}x}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\\
&=-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{\tan\frac x2-\frac x2}{\left(\frac x2\right)^3}}{4\left(1-\tan^2\frac x2\right)}-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(\frac{\tan\frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2}{4\left(1-\tan^2\frac x2\right)}\\
&=\frac L4-\frac14=-\frac13\end{align}$$
If you don't get to make that assumption, you can derive the first few terms of the series for [$\tan^{-1}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1788723/316404) or [$\sin^{-1}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786885/316404) algebraically using only [$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786480/316404) and then establish the desired limit, but that is relatively tough sledding.

Answer (score 0):

first :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{3}$$

proof:[Finding $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387271/finding-lim-x-to-0-frac-tan-x-xx3)

now:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}.\frac{x}{\tan x}=?$$

since :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\tan x}=1$$

so :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}=\frac{1}{3}$$